# Delete duplicated in a linked list solution from C++ to rust

Tags: c++, data-structures, rust, linked-list

I have this code solution written in c++ for the problem [remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/description/)  and just now I'm learning rust and I want to build the same solution in rust programming language my rust linkedList doesn't have ListNode have Option<Box<Node>>

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head) return head;

        ListNode* current = head;
        while (current->next) {
            if (current->next->val == current->val)
                current->next = current->next->next;
            else 
                current = current->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
};
```

If you know the rust way for write my c++ solution please share it with me and thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you want that with, or without, the memory leak that C++ "solution" exhibits?

Comment: In C++ you don't need all that, just use  the erase/remove idiom with [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: With memory leaks is good for me. because I know how solve it in C++ and rust and by other hand is funny but Leetcode rank better your solution if you don't use delete it doesn't have sense but is a fact.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for share info about  unique is useful but I try to implement my own linked list to prepare me for data structures interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn delete_duplicates(mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
```

by matching instead of just checking for .is_none() we can get the value inside
& check for None at the same time.

```rust
        // if (!head) return head;
        // ListNode* current = head;
        let mut current = match head.as_mut() {
            Some(c) => c,
            None => return head,
        };
```

Then we take the next item while checking it's there.
By using `.take()` we avoid having 2 mutable borrows of current, we'll also clean up the memory this way.

```rust
        // while (current->next) {
        while let Some(mut rest) = current.next.take() {
            // if (current->next->val == current->val)
            if rest.val == current.val {
                // current->next = current->next->next;
                current.next = rest.next;
            } else {
                // since we took earlier we gotta put it back
                current.next = Some(rest);
                // current = current->next;
                // unwrap is perfectly fine since we just set it to Some(rest)
                current = current.next.as_mut().unwrap();
            }
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

`.as_mut()` is just a way to turn a `&mut Option<T>` into `Option<&mut T>`

Comment: thanks for helping me and explaining how to write this code.
It looks like a simple code but you have to understand ownership, Option, reference, mut and match pattern which were the concepts you used and are not present in c++.
Again thanks you.